# How to duplicate DOM select element and retain selected option with JS/JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, state

I have a select element where a user can select an option. I want to be able to duplicate that element WHILE retaining the user selected option for use elsewhere on the page. .clone() does not retain the selected option. Any suggestions?

IMPORTANT EDIT:
I'm asking: Is there a workaround for:
"Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements."
?

Minimum Reproducible Example:

Expected Behavior:
1. A user selects an option from the select#favorite-color element.
2. The user then clicks the button#clone-li element
3. I want a deep copy of the li.color-picker element to be appended as a child to the ul.last element, ***WHILE*** retaining the selected option inside the cloned select#favorite-color element.

```
<ul class="first">
    <li class="color-picker">
        <select name="favorite-color" id="favorite-color">
            <option value="1">Blue</option>
            <option value="2" class="red">Red</option>
            <option value="3">Green</option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="last">
    
</ul>

<button type="button" id="clone-li">Clone Color Picker Li</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
    // ******************************** v INITIALIZE v ******************************** //
        // Variables:
            // DOM:
                var color_picker_li = $('li.color-picker');
                var favorite_color_select = $('select#favorite-color');
                var last_ul = $('ul.last');
                var clone_color_picker_li_button = $('button#clone-li')

        // States:
            // setTimeout(() => {
            //     $(favorite_color_select).find('option.red').prop('selected',true);

            //     setTimeout(() => {
            //         $(clone_color_picker_li_button).trigger('click');
                
            //     }, 3000);
            // }, 1500);
            
    // ******************************** ^ INITIALIZE ^ ******************************** //
    
    // ********************************** v EVENTS v ********************************** //
        // Handle a CLICK on the Cloen Color Picker Li Button:
            $(clone_color_picker_li_button).on('click', function() {
                $(color_picker_li).clone().appendTo(last_ul);
            });
        
    // ********************************** ^ EVENTS ^ ********************************** //
}); </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function to extend jQuery's built in ".clone()" function, to create a deep copy a set of matched elements with the dynamic state of all form elements copied to the cloned elements.

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/blackirishmec/jq-deepest-copy

Using this function in place of .clone() has solved my question.

Comment: @charlietfl finally figured it out, let me know what you think if you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of the clone based on value selected in the original

```js
$('select.sel').change(function(){
   const clone = $(this).clone().val(this.value);
   $('#cont').append(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">--pick one --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="cont">
<h3>Clone</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however what if it was a li with either a select or a textarea element as a child. I would love a way to copy that li regardless of it's children and have their value's retained.

Comment: Would help if you provided a [mcve] to help with your specific use case

Comment: Does that example provide more context @charlietfl ?

Comment: He said JS not jquery